# How can I flatten nested collection using GetProperties() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have the following object structure:

```
public class ReportDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public List<DetailsDTO> Details { get; set; }
}

public class DetailsDTO
{
    public string DetailName { get; set; }
    public string DetailAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to create excel from that, if there is multiple `Details` then columns will be duplicated. So the result in columns might looks like that:
`Name | Identifier | DetailName | DetailAmount | DetailName | DetailAmount ...`

To achive that I need to use reflaction to GetProperties. And when it comes to the main object ReportDTO is very easy.

```
private void FillSheet<T>(ICollection<T> data)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = data.First().GetType().GetProperties();
   ... // here I'm populating sheet based on those properties
}
```

But as I mentioned I need to include also Properties from `List<DetailsDTO> Details` so these properties need to be flatten.

So somehow `var properties` should return `PropertyInfo[]` with following values:

```
[
  {System.String Name}
  {System.String Identifier}
  {System.String DetailName}
  {System.String DetailAmount}
  {System.String DetailName}
  {System.String DetailAmount}
 ...
]
```

instead of this:

```
[
  {System.String Name}
  {System.String Identifier}
  {System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...]}  
]
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: And what are `Name`, `Detail`, `DetailName` and `DetailAmount`? How do they relate to properties?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean, what is `DetailName` in property, for instance?

Comment: Some string that I get from database. Look at the class'es at the top of the post.

Comment: It's still not clear: you're looking for a way to fill `ReportDTO` or you already have filled `ReportDTO` and you need to flatten it?

Comment: I want to map RaportDTO to PropertyInfo[] where every properties will be on the same level (even those nested)

Comment: This is what I'm asking what from Property is written to ReportDTO? Could you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the types there is little need to use reflection:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetValues(ReportDTO dto)
    {
        yield return dto.Name;
        yield return dto.Identifier;
        foreach (var details in dto.Details)
        {
            yield return details.DetailName;
            yield return details.DetailAmount;
        }
    }
```

If this is one of several possible types you can simply add checks `if(data is ReportDTO report) ...`, or use a [pattern matching switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) or the visitor pattern. The visitor pattern has the advantage that it lets you restrict the generic type to a specific interface, where the visitor can be forced by the compiler to handle all types implementing that interface, improving type safety.

Reflection can be used if you need to handle *any* kind of object, or want to use attributes to annotate the properties. But this adds a fair bit of complexity since the object and its properties form a graph that needs to be traversed. And you would need to handle circular references and many other potential issues.

Comment: Actually I don't know the type. It should be fully generic. As it will be used by multiple DTOs. That logic will be in ExcelService that generates excel file based on any DTO

Comment: @DiPix In that case you have a much larger problem than stated in the question. I would reconsider the design since it would either require a very large amount of work, or only work for some specific classes. Just as an example, if you iterate over all properties recursively and only select the leaves you would get a list of Lengths of each string, probably not what you want. Check how serialization libraries like json.Net work for something similar.

Comment: You could check if a property implements IEnumerable, and then enumerate all the objects in it. But remember that string is also en IEnumerable! So you would be iterating over characters in each string, So you would either get a empty list, or a list of all characters .